# How to access observable data from a class in the component?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have declared the data I want from the API using observable in a separate class. I want to access the data declared in the separate class into my component class. But javascript being asynchronous in nature will give me `undefined` once the control crosses the function call of the observable method. So is there a way to 'subscribe' to this function that already contains an observable that is fetching data or any other way of accessing data from getData() in GetDataClass.ts into my Component class?

Here's the code:
`GetDataClass.ts`

```
  Data: any;
  getData() {
          this.dataservice.getAllData()
               .subscribe(response => {
                    this.temp = response;
                    this.Data = this.temp.ReturnData.DataList;
                    console.log('this.data new: ', this.Data);
               }, err => console.log('error: ', err))
     }
```

`AppComponent`:

```
data: any;
constructor(private dataService: GetDataClass ...){
    this.dataService.getData();
    this.data = this.dataService.temp
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you wish to "share" the observable values as you wouldn't want to make multiple requests to the server side for the same set of data.

There are multiple RxJS operators you can make use of, such [publishReplay()](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/publishReplay) and [shareReplay()](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/multicasting/sharereplay.html).

For instance, in your `dataservice`, we can modify `getData` to make use of `publishReplay()` to fire the cached values.

```
import { publishReplay, refCount } from 'rxjs/operators';

getData() {
  return this.http.get(`api-request`)
    .pipe(
      publishReplay(1),
      refCount()
    );
}
```

Similarly, we could make use of `shareReplay`.

```
import { shareReplay } from 'rxjs/operators';

getData() {
  return this.http.get(`api-request`)
    .pipe(
      shareReplay({refCount: true, bufferSize: 1})
    );
}
```

On your `AppComponent` class, you can subscribe to `getData()` as per usual, yet avoiding multiple requests to the same endpoint.

```
res: any;

ngOnInit(){
  this.dataService.getData().subscribe(data => {
    this.res = data;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have `class A` which gets the data and `class B` which consumes the data, you could to the following:

- create a subject in `A` so that every time new data comes in, you can can emit the data. You also need to expose this subject as a public observable, so other consumers can get notified when data comes in:

```js
// `A` class
private _data$ = new Subject();
data$ = this._data$.asObservable();

getData () {
 this.apiService.get(...)
   .subscribe(results => {
    this._data$.next(results);
 })
}
```

- create a consumer of `class A`. In this case, it will be called `class B`. Here you would import the class A and subscribe to the observable it exposes:

```js
// `B` class

constructor (private aService: AService) { }

ngOnInit () {
 this.aService.getData();

 // Subscribe so you can get the new data every time
 this.aService.data$
  .subscribe(data => {
   // Do something with the data..
 })
}
```

Comment: very bad way to return data from observable

Comment: AFAIK, that's actually a common way of doing things. Could you elaborate on why this is a bad practice?

Comment: If you already have an Observable, it seems unnecessary to create a Subject to wrap it?

Comment: Yes, effectively the `share()` operator does the wrapping in a Subject for you, no need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @DeborahK  Now I see. I initially thought that the incoming data would also be needed inside the A class. Otherwise, it seems indeed unnecessary, I could be simply returned the observable from ‘getData’. Thank you for the feedback!!